# Best practices for storing the schema of delimited text files

Tags: c#, schema, flat-file, csv

I am writing a program that parses several delimited flat files from which it needs several of the columns. I am not sure of the best way to make my code easy to maintain/update in the event of future changes to the format of input flat files.

Currently I have a set of constant ints of the form (there are many more of these):

```
NameListFirstNameCol = 0; 
NameListLastNameCol = 1; 
NameListAgeCol = 2; 
ClassListRoomNumCol = 0; 
ClassListRoomNameCol = 1;
```

As well as constants for the delimiters such as:

```
NameListDelim = ',';
ClassListDelim = '\t';
```

I wanted to see if anyone had suggestions on a better way to keep track of this sort of information. (I can assume that the columns I need will always be in the inputs, but that the creator of the inputs might change the delimiter, add new columns, or reorder the columns). This is for a data analysis script which will see some reuse, but is not a major piece of production software.

Comment: I like to keep a sample input in comments for ease of verification

Answer (score 0):

Here is some interesting information:

[Importing CSV file into Database with Schema.ini](http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/Importing_CSV_Database_Schema.ini.aspx)

Especially the section **Import a CSV file every time with DIFFERENT CSV file name or
Dynamically creating Schema.ini File** might look promising.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create a list with field names and corresponding indexes from the file.
For example Dictionary< string, int > for keeping the names that you can read from the first row of the file. Having the list of the column names and corresponding indexes you can use [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to parse following rows using only the indexes you do need.
Also you have to store the list of the columns required for your structure. For easy maintaince you can keep it as a in separate class inside separate .cs file.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a library called [JRecordBind](http://jrecordbind.org/) that describes the structure of flat files using XML Schema. See [one of the examples](https://github.com/ffissore/jrecordbind/tree/master/jrecordbind-test/src/test/resources).

Unfortunately it's written in Java. You may consider porting it. It would be great to have a C# version